# cannot find symbol method setJSMainModueName(string)

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

previously my project works and today it asked to remove the override method from public List> createJSModules().

I did removal from all packages and not I am getting error as

Error:(57, 17) error: cannot find symbol method setJSMainModuleName(String)

I am not sure how to resolve this

Comment: I'm getting the same thing out of the blue. Everything was working fine yesterday. No changes to `package.json` or anything. I wonder if something's going on with npm packages.

Answer (score 9):

Its possible your Build.gradle file is referencing the React Native libraries using a wildcard

`implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'`

Make sure its set to an explicit version.

which could have pulled down a new version of RN when you ran compile

I got bit by this too but the method `setJSMainModuleName` has been renamed to `setJSMainModulePath` as can be seen in this commit:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/5d4c6e5f23e3f7f64576cccff76822d4b7635ab1

Answer (score 1):

### Specify React Native Version in `build.gradle`

In your app's `build.gradle` file, change your React Native dependency to this:

```
compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.52.0") { force = true }
```

*(Replacing `0.52.0` with the React Native version in your `package.json` file.)*

- Don't forget the parentheses around `"com.facebook.react:react-native:0.52.0"`.

This was an issue that came up yesterday/today and can found here on Github:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19259